# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

When I run Grails application that is created using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2,this error display.I already set up the environment for the java and grails.

Could someone please help me? I already googled and tried a lot, i still cannot slove it. please help me. Grails version is 2.3.11.Do I need to download grails-docs also?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, it's a warning and can be ignored. Permgen was removed in Java 8, so specifying the min and or max size isn't needed.

I don't use NetBeans but you can make this go away if you can configure the JVM args, otherwise just ignore it.

Comment: how can we configure and what JVM args ??